# Spring WebFlux and WebClient change response on error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I have some controller method like

```
@PostMapping("/*")
fun proxy(@RequestBody body: String): Mono<ByteArray> {
    return roundRobinBean.getNext()
        .post()
        .uri("/api")
        .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(body))
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono<ByteArray>()
        .doOnSuccess{
            threadPool.submit(PutToCacheJob(body, it, cacheBean))
        }
        .doOnError{
            logger.error(it.message, it)
        }
}
```

roundRobinBean return WebClient for some host. If i get connection timeout exception or get 500 response i need call another host or return data from cache. Have mono some handler for changing inner data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`onErrorResume`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#onErrorResume-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.function.Function-) operator which lets you define a fallback in case of errors.